# Why did package-lock.json change the integrity hash from sha1 to sha512?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

I just generated a new npm lockfile, package-lock.json, as part of my typical workflow. But I noticed that this time all of the integrity hashes have been changed from sha1 to sha512. What is happening here?

[image]

```
"chalk": {
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-2.0.1.tgz",
-   "integrity": "sha1-ce5R+nvkyuwaY4OffmgtgTLTDK8=",
+   "integrity": "sha512-lyuxPGr/Wfhrlem2CL/UcnUc1zcqKAImBDzukY7Y5F/yQiNdko6+fRLevlw1HgMySw7f611UIY408EtxRSoK3Q==",
    […]
}
```

Comment: It's an issue with npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17749

Comment: The issue referenced above has been closed and now an article is created to instruct how to solve this problem: https://npm.community/t/shasum-check-or-integrity-eintegrity-errors/153

Comment: The above npm.community link is a 404 now.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

From what I can see, npm changed the integrity checksum from sha1 to sha512.

If your git changes are going from sha1 to sha512, you should do that update once and it will be good after that.

If someone else working with the codebase and sees a git change from sha512 down to sha1 (which is the issue I was having) you can fix it by running the following:

Discard the changes in git for package-lock.json

```
npm i -g npm
rm -rf node_modules/
npm i
```

This will update npm and reinstall all of your packages so that the new checksum (sha512) is present.

Comment: Is there a reason to use sha512 over sha1? My computer is currently the one changing to sha1 for our environment.

Comment: @Elijah1210 I'm going to guess less possibility of 'faking' the hash with a collision?

Comment: This wasn't sufficient in my case. In addition to delete the `node_modules` folder, I needed `npm cache clear --force` too.

Comment: @Elijah1210 _"The basic difference between SHA1 and SHA512 is the length of hash values generated by both algorithms – SHA1 has a 160-bit hash value while SHA512 has a 512-bit hash value. Therefore, making SHA512 a much more secure algorithm."_ (In case of node modules, the probability of a collision is much lower.)

Comment: Warning: If your node version is no longer supported by the latest version of npm, the first command in this answer will just break your npm and you will have to reinstall using another package manager, or download from nodejs.org.

Answer (score 53):

Building on what Dave answered.  The fix i found was to do the following:

```
npm i -g npm

cd {working directory}
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm i
```

We did this for all our developers at the same time and this stopped the sha-512 vs sha-1 issue which was causing frustrating merge conflicts.

Comment: You should never remove you package-lock.json file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210331/681803

Comment: I needed to revert rather than remove package-lock.json.

Comment: This worked for me. I agree with @ThdK, you should not need to remove package-lock.json. Simply revert it to a correct state, then follow the steps in this answer (without removing package-lock)

Answer (score 10):

See also https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17749 which although claims the issue is 'fixed', it isn't. Removing `node_modules` is a workaround.

There may be a relationship with operating systems. We're hitting this right now with developers on Linux and Windows platforms.

Comment: We moved to yarn in the end.

Comment: Every NPM problem seemingly resolved by moving to Yarn

Answer (score 7):

I'm working in big team. Forcing every developer to force clean `npm` cache is difficult and not reliable. Also, this doesn't help every time. So, for anyone who still facing this npm issue (same as me) and nothing else helps – try this git based tool I've built recently: https://github.com/kopach/lockfix. It reverts `sha512 -> sha1` integrity changes of npm's lock files. If you add this to your `postshrinkwrap` script of `package.json` - you should eventually get all integrity properties set to `sha512` and have lock file consistent.

```sh
npm install --save-dev lockfix
```

```
"scripts": {
    "postshrinkwrap": "lockfix",
},
```

Comment: curious, can that be run via npx instead?

Comment: @GeorgeWL, yes, check README for details https://github.com/kopach/lockfix#manually-from-terminal

Answer (score 6):

As @Daniel Cumings I also had to remove the `package-lock.json` to get rid of the sha1 hashes. Here's the **Windows CLI commands** for reference, which does the same as Daniel's script:

```
npm i -g npm
rd /s /q "node_modules"
del package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm i
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `npm` v5 or later, and you're seeing the integrity hashes changing from sha512 back to sha1, one way to remedy that *without* removing your `package-lock.json` is to do the following:

1. Remove all the sha1 integrity hashes from your `package-lock.json` ([do not remove your `package-lock.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127283/3575560)); for example:

   ```
   diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json
   index 6374e258..05f77ec8 100644
   --- a/package-lock.json
   +++ b/package-lock.json
   @@ -56,12 +56,10 @@
        "@babel/core": {
          "version": "7.9.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.9.6.tgz",
   -      "integrity": "sha1-X+QF1VU04G078GD4anmTXNpfZhU="
        },
        "@babel/parser": {
          "version": "7.9.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-adobe-release/@babel/traverse/-/traverse-7.9.6.tgz",
   -      "integrity": "sha1-fGzlDyLGPvCJNpHXPZrCdGz7QSY="
        },
   ```
2. Remove your `node_modules`: `rm -rf node_modules`
3. Clear the npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`
4. Install the packages: `npm install`

This should result in your `package-lock.json` updated with the sha512 integrity hashes.

Comment: Package-lock states this in big letters:
This is an auto-generated file, NEVER modify it manually

Comment: @GeorgeWL - the proposed solution is a workaround for the integrity SHA checksums only, and is not intended in the sense to modify other aspects of the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that one should NEVER manually edit the package-lock

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this issue by doing the below following changes:

1. Ensure npm version: 7.x or above
2. Create a `.npmrc` file

```
// .npmrc
lockfile-version=3
```

3. Remove your `node_modules`: `rm -rf node_modules/`
4. Remove existing `package-lock.json`: `rm package-lock.json`
5. Install npm packages: `npm install`

You can check the integration hash:

```
$ grep -o 'sha1' package-lock.json | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This most likely happened because you changed the `node` version you're using.
Newer version of `npm` use `hash512`.

In my case I work in a shared project and what happened is I ran a FRESH `npm i` with a newer version of `npm` which caused my `package-lock` file to be changed to use `hash512`. After that, I refreshed my branch, i.e `git reset --hard && git pull`, which brought to me a `package-lock` file with `SHA1` checksums.
Because I still had my `node_modules` installed with a newer version of `npm` right after doing `git pull` I ran `npm i` which changed my `package-lock` file to use `hash512`.

The tl;dr is:

1. Make sure you're using the correct node version for the project, prefer using `nvm use`
2. `rm -Rf node_modules && npm i` (you MUST do rm -Rf node_modules, otherwise you will keep getting package-lock changes)

This should keep your project consistent

Answer (score 1):

### Works on node 14

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean --force
sed -i '' 's/"sha1-.*"/""/g' package-lock.json
npm i
```

`rm -rf node_modules/` - remove node_modules from project to remove persisted packages with sha1 integrities

`npm cache clean --force` - remove cached modules and integrities

`sed -i '' 's/"sha1-.*"/""/g' package-lock.json` - replace all sha1 integrities by empty strings

`npm i` - to update integrities in package-lock.json, node_modules and npm cache.

Result:

- "npm i" will always install packages with sha512 integrity.
- Even if one of the developers does not follow this instruction and commits sha-1 - reinstalling (npm i) on your machine will return sha512 back.

Answer (score -2):

In my case `npm -g i npm` was not enough, I had to modify PATH to point new npm at begining.

To check it without modification try `/usr/local/bin/npm i` instead of `npm i`.

Answer (score -4):

Further building on previous comments and suggestions, for me I needed to wipe the existing node_modules folder, the cache, and then grab the sha512 package-lock.json file from git (which was committed from another computer), and finally do an npm i. Something like this:

```sh
npm i -g npm
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clear --force
git reset --hard
npm i
```

After this package-lock.json used sha512 and other changes stabilized.

Comment: is `git reset --hard` really needed in this case?