# Why does npm-shrinkwrap.json change when running npm install

Tags: node.js, git, npm

We use NPM Shrinkwrap to lock down dependencies.

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature but when I run: npm install after deleting my node_modules directory everything works but my npm-shrinkwrap.json will always have a few changes that I have to commit to git...

The changes are usually minor, such as changing the "integrity" hash from sha-1 to sha-512 (or vice versa). Or a package will simply be moved to a new line in the file but the content does not change.

Again, nothing breaks when these changes happen, all the correct node_modules are installed, but it is annoying to keep committing this file to git when we are not making any changes.

Any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: See this q & a here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638381/what-did-package-lock-json-change-the-integrity-hash-from-sha1-to-sha512

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't hesitate to the use the `git update-index --assume-unchanged npm-shrinkwrap.json` command.

Then if you need to make changes and commit them run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged npm-shrinkwrap.json` so Git will see the changes and enable you to stage and commit them.

Comment: If you want try a different approach, take a look at the advice in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638381/why-did-package-lock-json-change-the-integrity-hash-from-sha1-to-sha512?noredirect=1&lq=1