# Netflix conductor server local docker container is unhealthy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netflix-conductor

I am following the steps [here](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running) to install & run `Netflix Conductor` locally on my desktop. I am trying to use `docker-compose` to bring all the services up. After initial problems of incorrect docker version, docker compose version, docker compose build problem (solved using [this](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/issues/702)), I have hit a roadblock with this error -

> /conductor/docker$ sudo docker-compose up
>
> docker_elasticsearch_1 is up-to-date
>
> docker_dynomite_1 is up-to-date
>
> ERROR: for conductor-server  Container "a89b4c61d465" is unhealthy.
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Also i changed elasticsearch port to 10300 in docker-compose.yaml, server/config/config.properties & server/config/config-local.properties.

Docker compose version is 1.23.2. Docker version is 18.09.3.

PS: I am extremely new to dockers & related concepts.

More info: reverted my port change to default (9200/9300) & added docker information of unhealthy container (docker container-id changed due to re-build)

> /conductor/docker$ sudo docker ps -a --filter "id=7be9f9b5288c"
>   [sudo] password for anshuman: 
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                            NAMES
>
> 7be9f9b5288c        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.8   "/bin/bash bin/es-do…"   36 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   docker_elasticsearch_1

`curl` to elasticsearch seems ok.

> /conductor/docker$ curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/health
>   1553188720 17:18:40 docker-cluster yellow 1 1 5 5 0 0 5 0 - 50.0%

Docker logs for the container give me this (no clue what they mean)

> /conductor/docker$ sudo docker logs 7be9f9b5288c
>   [2019-03-21T17:12:06,323][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MachineLearningTemplateRegistry] [M5hkiIZ] successfully created .ml-meta index template
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:06,413][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MachineLearningTemplateRegistry] [M5hkiIZ] successfully created .ml-notifications index template
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:06,502][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MachineLearningTemplateRegistry] [M5hkiIZ] successfully created .ml-anomalies- index template
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:07,152][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [M5hkiIZ] license [dfac41a4-9280-4c77-81ef-0f943039ef77] mode [trial] - valid
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:15,712][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [M5hkiIZ] [.monitoring-es-6-2019.03.21] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-es], shards [1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running)/[1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), mappings [doc]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:16,122][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [M5hkiIZ] [.watches] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [watches], shards [1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running)/[1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), mappings [watch]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:12:16,728][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [M5hkiIZ] [.watches/t05gsw2UQjmWEJ9IiSKn6g] update_mapping [watch]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:13:17,111][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [M5hkiIZ] [.triggered_watches] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [triggered_watches], shards [1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running)/[1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), mappings [triggered_watch]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:13:17,644][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [M5hkiIZ] [.monitoring-alerts-6] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-alerts], shards [1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running)/[1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), mappings [doc]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:13:17,918][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [M5hkiIZ] [.watcher-history-6-2019.03.21] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.watch-history-6], shards [1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running)/[1](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), mappings [doc]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:13:18,475][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [M5hkiIZ] [.watcher-history-6-2019.03.21/sP8OvfXNSmCImfRf3mCR3A] update_mapping [doc]
>
> [2019-03-21T17:13:18,718][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [M5hkiIZ] [.watcher-history-6-2019.03.21/sP8OvfXNSmCImfRf3mCR3A] update_mapping [doc]

Comment: Who is `a89b4c61d465`? `docker ps -a --filter "id= a89b4c61d465"` should tell us that.

Comment: Added that information in the question. Looks like `docker_elasticsearch_1` container is unhealthy. And looks like something to do with port configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the problems to make this work. It required to at least get to know the basics of how `docker` and `Dockerfile` work.

1. Based on the documentation [here](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/architecture/#installing-and-running), I started the local server & was attempting to bring everything up using `docker-compose`. This gave me a port conflict.
2. I resorted to incorrectly change port for `elasticsearch`. Realized this after I learnt basics of `Dockerfile`. This was the reason for my unhealthy container.
3. Then there were errors in building conductor-ui.

   > npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY

   This required a change in `Dockerfile` for conductor-ui. The `npm install` command was changed to `npm install --no-shrinkwrap --update-binary` (based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0?answertab=votes#tab-top)). Other answers for [this issue](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/issues/1054)