# React Native - npm install give me an EPERM: opration not permitted, unlink error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I discovered react native about 2 hours ago, so I wanted to try. So I launched my console and typed 'npm install create-react-native-app -g', the installation went well, I decided to create a project. So I typed 'create-react-native-app ReactNativeTest', and there It's disaster, an error of integrity, I searched long enough on the net to find a solution, but what I find is not suited to my problem, here are my logs:

```
17799 warn expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.55.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
17800 warn react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
17801 warn react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
17802 warn url-loader@1.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
17803 verbose stack Error: sha512-+taJh7bN2owmwaZpJUrNpHdmPAL6ZynNCZj15uLQgjaPFq0ZBIG2ZWuSJ48eGoUjAb3lrWxkmLlHb2eJFXc7sQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-+taJh7bN2owmwaZpJUrNpHdmPAL6ZynNCZj15uLQgjaPFq0ZBIG2ZWuSJ48eGoUjAb3lrWxkmLlHb2eJFXc7sQ== but got sha512-bD0JKadHSxamqfa/Fgbnh9CoUrFDmLMPdQmEdRPIquZLWHvo19U1kfeo3F0y0kVZfD4u4pCXP12Nj6ZY+X9Q7Q==. (1304678 bytes)
17803 verbose stack     at Transform.on (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ssri\index.js:275:19)
17803 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
17803 verbose stack     at Transform.emit (events.js:208:7)
17803 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
17803 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
17803 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
17804 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projets\ReactNativeTest
17805 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17806 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
17807 verbose node v8.11.4
17808 verbose npm  v5.6.0
17809 error code EINTEGRITY
17810 error sha512-+taJh7bN2owmwaZpJUrNpHdmPAL6ZynNCZj15uLQgjaPFq0ZBIG2ZWuSJ48eGoUjAb3lrWxkmLlHb2eJFXc7sQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-+taJh7bN2owmwaZpJUrNpHdmPAL6ZynNCZj15uLQgjaPFq0ZBIG2ZWuSJ48eGoUjAb3lrWxkmLlHb2eJFXc7sQ== but got sha512-bD0JKadHSxamqfa/Fgbnh9CoUrFDmLMPdQmEdRPIquZLWHvo19U1kfeo3F0y0kVZfD4u4pCXP12Nj6ZY+X9Q7Q==. (1304678 bytes)
17811 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**EDIT:** I've tried an 'npm i npm', and I get *the same error*

**EDIT2:** I've tried an 'npm clean cache --force' and it give me a new error:

```
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I run \`npm install\`, it returns with \`ERR! code EINTEGRITY\` (npm 5.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0)

Comment: Yes I just saw, I'm really sorry, so I did a `npm cache clean --force`, it worked, but now the` npm install` gives me another error:
`npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink`

He advises me to run the command as administrator, but even as administrator he brings me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: downgraded to npm@5.3