# npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY while npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

When I try to make npm install, I got this error

```
  npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
    npm ERR! 
    sha512-boQj1WFgQH3v4clhu3mTNfP+vOBxorDlE8EKiMjUlLG3C4qAESnn9AxIOkFgTR2c9LtzNjPrjS60cT27ZKBhaA== 
    integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-boQj1WFgQH3v4clhu3mTNfP+vOBxorDlE8EKiMjUlLG3C4qAESnn9AxIOkFgTR2c9LtzNjPrjS60cT27ZKBhaA== but got sha5
        12-jGhWI9FADblpQKmyQF4BghrHs6FLV3dYFHVWcvj0xIUzHuO41PPfUlZOUplwasz72FRE2Knsa0wWubWldC9Jpw==. (3240 bytes)
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
        npm WARN tar invalid entry
```

I tried,

```
npm cache verify
npm cache clean --force
```

I have already delete package-lock.json file,

Add proxy to .npmrc and other confs like strict-ssl=false, 
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

versions :

```
npm version
{ npm: '6.11.3',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '64.2',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '4',
  nghttp2: '1.39.2',
  node: '10.16.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1c',
  tz: '2019a',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.28.0',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.54',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }

node -v
v10.16.3
```

Comment: You should provide deails of the npm version, and the contents of your package.json. Did you try to identify which package is actually giving an error. Maybe the recent packages that you added is causing a problem.

Comment: C:\Users\I_SAHIN15>npm version
{ npm: '6.11.3',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '64.2',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '4',
  nghttp2: '1.39.2',
  node: '10.16.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1c',
  tz: '2019a',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.28.0',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.54',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }

C:\Users\I_SAHIN15>node -v
v10.16.3

Comment: did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0

Comment: Yes, I have already checked related question but it has't work for me.

Comment: @İlyasŞahin Have you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Beauceron yes, resolved.  ıt was all relevant with internet connection, after some firewall configuration its solved.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json

   `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
2. Install npm

   `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

You deleted `package-lock.json`, so the following would probably be of no use for you. In my case it worked. But first make sure you understand what's going on. `npm` tells you that the checksum from https://registry.npm.org doesn't match the one from `package-lock.json`. Either it changed in the registry, or...

Consider a line from the output:

```
npm ERR! 
  sha512-boQj1WFgQH3v4clhu3mTNfP+vOBxorDlE8EKiMjUlLG3C4qAESnn9AxIOkFgTR2c9LtzNjPrjS60cT27ZKBhaA== 
integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted
  sha512-boQj1WFgQH3v4clhu3mTNfP+vOBxorDlE8EKiMjUlLG3C4qAESnn9AxIOkFgTR2c9LtzNjPrjS60cT27ZKBhaA==
but got
  sha512-jGhWI9FADblpQKmyQF4BghrHs6FLV3dYFHVWcvj0xIUzHuO41PPfUlZOUplwasz72FRE2Knsa0wWubWldC9Jpw==
. (3240 bytes)
```

Find the package in `package-lock.json` by the first two integrity checksums (`sha512-b...`), and put the third one (`sha512-j...`) into its "integrity" field.

More on it [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/473#issuecomment-635677353).

Answer (score 0):

In case my case, I found the conflict coming from private proxy repository after I try all these suggestions around internet.

If you also downloaded npm package via a private repository(e.g. Sonatype Nexus). You should find the conflict packages and delete it from your proxy repository. I guest the same version packages of main repository have been updated but proxy repository cache the previous update.

I fixed it by deleted the entire folder of package"@babel"
[image: screen shot]