# Angular JS: Karma not installing in project folder. ERR! code EINTEGRITY

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, karma-jasmine

Im learning angular JS currently and im trying to learn unit testing. I was instructed to use karma and Jasmine for my unit testing and Im currently trying to set it up.after installing JS node and performing the global installation  i keep getting the error below thats putting up an EEINTEGRITY error code.Any ideas? Here is the error shown along with the full log of the run performed below.

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== but got sha512-ALpfN/W8faBisExChxWPuhT1Qnp0P2OVFYaRHMj/j5tZXE3/uxLDvf9BtIdbBuCqMp258SHJPz2JbxEX37EG/Q==. (2082 bytes)
```

Here is a complete log of the run shown above

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'karma'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\HP/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session aa0738418c1931c7
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData
8 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/karma 1451ms
9 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-5.0.9.tgz 2392ms
10 silly pacote tag manifest for karma@latest fetched in 3968ms
11 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 4234ms
12 silly install loadIdealTree
13 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
15 silly install loadShrinkwrap
16 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 10ms
17 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
18 silly resolveWithNewModule karma@5.0.9 checking installable status
19 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser 752ms
20 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dom-serialize 745ms
21 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/di 806ms
22 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/braces 884ms (from cache)
23 silly pacote range manifest for braces@^3.0.2 fetched in 902ms
24 silly resolveWithNewModule braces@3.0.2 checking installable status
25 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob 914ms (from cache)
26 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/colors 956ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote range manifest for glob@^7.1.6 fetched in 979ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule glob@7.1.6 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs 1053ms (from cache)
30 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/flatted 1192ms
31 silly pacote range manifest for graceful-fs@^4.2.4 fetched in 1265ms
32 silly resolveWithNewModule graceful-fs@4.2.4 checking installable status
33 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/di/-/di-0.0.1.tgz 545ms
34 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile 392ms
35 silly pacote range manifest for di@^0.0.1 fetched in 1392ms
36 silly resolveWithNewModule di@0.0.1 checking installable status
37 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dom-serialize/-/dom-serialize-2.2.1.tgz 689ms
38 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.19.0.tgz 792ms
39 silly pacote range manifest for dom-serialize@^2.2.1 fetched in 1588ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule dom-serialize@2.2.1 checking installable status
41 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy 685ms
42 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz 678ms
43 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/flatted/-/flatted-2.0.2.tgz 447ms
44 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar 1697ms
45 silly pacote range manifest for body-parser@^1.19.0 fetched in 1705ms
46 silly resolveWithNewModule body-parser@1.19.0 checking installable status
47 silly pacote range manifest for colors@^1.4.0 fetched in 1710ms
48 silly resolveWithNewModule colors@1.4.0 checking installable status
49 silly pacote range manifest for flatted@^2.0.2 fetched in 1709ms
50 silly resolveWithNewModule flatted@2.0.2 checking installable status
51 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile/-/isbinaryfile-4.0.6.tgz 337ms
52 silly pacote range manifest for isbinaryfile@^4.0.6 fetched in 900ms
53 silly resolveWithNewModule isbinaryfile@4.0.6 checking installable status
54 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash 668ms (from cache)
55 silly pacote range manifest for lodash@^4.17.15 fetched in 714ms
56 silly resolveWithNewModule lodash@4.17.15 checking installable status
57 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser 664ms
58 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/qjobs 673ms
59 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime 841ms
60 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch 741ms (from cache)
61 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-1.18.1.tgz 880ms
62 silly pacote range manifest for http-proxy@^1.18.1 fetched in 1647ms
63 silly resolveWithNewModule http-proxy@1.18.1 checking installable status
64 silly pacote range manifest for minimatch@^3.0.4 fetched in 883ms
65 silly resolveWithNewModule minimatch@3.0.4 checking installable status
66 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 740ms (from cache)
67 silly pacote range manifest for rimraf@^3.0.2 fetched in 802ms
68 silly resolveWithNewModule rimraf@3.0.2 checking installable status
69 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/connect 2772ms
70 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar/-/chokidar-3.4.0.tgz 1126ms
71 silly pacote range manifest for chokidar@^3.0.0 fetched in 2842ms
72 silly resolveWithNewModule chokidar@3.4.0 checking installable status
73 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-1.2.1.tgz 538ms
74 silly pacote range manifest for range-parser@^1.2.1 fetched in 1243ms
75 silly resolveWithNewModule range-parser@1.2.1 checking installable status
76 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map 456ms (from cache)
77 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/qjobs/-/qjobs-1.2.0.tgz 611ms
78 silly pacote range manifest for qjobs@^1.2.0 fetched in 1405ms
79 silly resolveWithNewModule qjobs@1.2.0 checking installable status
80 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ua-parser-js 447ms
81 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io 1210ms
82 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/tmp 598ms (from cache)
83 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-3.7.0.tgz 593ms
84 http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/yargs 542ms (from cache)
85 silly pacote range manifest for connect@^3.7.0 fetched in 3437ms
86 silly resolveWithNewModule connect@3.7.0 checking installable status
87 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-2.4.5.tgz 966ms
88 silly pacote range manifest for mime@^2.4.5 fetched in 1854ms
89 silly resolveWithNewModule mime@2.4.5 checking installable status
90 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for source-map@^0.6.1 sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== but got sha512-ALpfN/W8faBisExChxWPuhT1Qnp0P2OVFYaRHMj/j5tZXE3/uxLDvf9BtIdbBuCqMp258SHJPz2JbxEX37EG/Q==. (2082 bytes)
91 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-2.3.0.tgz 705ms
92 silly pacote range manifest for socket.io@^2.3.0 fetched in 1946ms
93 silly resolveWithNewModule socket.io@2.3.0 checking installable status
94 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.2.1.tgz 889ms
95 silly pacote version manifest for tmp@0.2.1 fetched in 1551ms
96 silly resolveWithNewModule tmp@0.2.1 checking installable status
97 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/log4js 2868ms
98 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ua-parser-js/-/ua-parser-js-0.7.21.tgz 1168ms
99 silly pacote version manifest for ua-parser-js@0.7.21 fetched in 1652ms
100 silly resolveWithNewModule ua-parser-js@0.7.21 checking installable status
101 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/log4js/-/log4js-6.2.1.tgz 509ms
102 silly pacote range manifest for log4js@^6.2.1 fetched in 3453ms
103 silly resolveWithNewModule log4js@6.2.1 checking installable status
104 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/yargs/-/yargs-15.3.1.tgz 1443ms
105 silly pacote range manifest for yargs@^15.3.1 fetched in 2035ms
106 silly resolveWithNewModule yargs@15.3.1 checking installable status
107 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
108 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 9154ms
109 silly saveTree HP
109 silly saveTree +-- karma@5.0.9
109 silly saveTree | +-- body-parser@1.19.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- braces@3.0.2
109 silly saveTree | +-- chokidar@3.4.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- colors@1.4.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- connect@3.7.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- di@0.0.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- dom-serialize@2.2.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- flatted@2.0.2
109 silly saveTree | +-- glob@7.1.6
109 silly saveTree | | `-- minimatch@3.0.4
109 silly saveTree | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.4
109 silly saveTree | +-- http-proxy@1.18.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- isbinaryfile@4.0.6
109 silly saveTree | +-- lodash@4.17.15
109 silly saveTree | +-- log4js@6.2.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- mime@2.4.5
109 silly saveTree | +-- minimatch@3.0.4
109 silly saveTree | +-- qjobs@1.2.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- range-parser@1.2.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- rimraf@3.0.2
109 silly saveTree | +-- socket.io@2.3.0
109 silly saveTree | +-- tmp@0.2.1
109 silly saveTree | +-- ua-parser-js@0.7.21
109 silly saveTree | `-- yargs@15.3.1
109 silly saveTree `-- popper.js@1.15.0
110 verbose stack Error: sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== but got sha512-ALpfN/W8faBisExChxWPuhT1Qnp0P2OVFYaRHMj/j5tZXE3/uxLDvf9BtIdbBuCqMp258SHJPz2JbxEX37EG/Q==. (2082 bytes)
110 verbose stack     at Transform.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ssri\index.js:328:19)
110 verbose stack     at Transform.emit (events.js:215:7)
110 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
110 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
111 verbose cwd C:\Users\HP\Documents\web dev\Angular1
112 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.10240
113 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "karma"
114 verbose node v12.14.0
115 verbose npm  v6.13.4
116 error code EINTEGRITY
117 error sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g== but got sha512-ALpfN/W8faBisExChxWPuhT1Qnp0P2OVFYaRHMj/j5tZXE3/uxLDvf9BtIdbBuCqMp258SHJPz2JbxEX37EG/Q==. (2082 bytes)
118 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: seems like your problem is similar with:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I run \`npm install\`, it returns with \`ERR! code EINTEGRITY\` (npm 5.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0)