# In React, how do I import JSON file as a URL instead of contents?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I know that in a Create React App project, one can import images like this:

```js
import image from './image.png'
```

This would result in `image` variable assigned not to actual image data, but a URL, which one then fetches or puts into an `src` attribute.

By default this doesn't work the same way for `.json` files: they are bundled and imported as full content instead. But since in my case the JSON quite big, I don't want to bundle it. Instead I want to have a URL, which I would fetch separately, same as with images. How do I do that?

I don't want to eject, but I can use `@craco/craco` to override something in config if needed.

Comment: Hi @1valdis, sorry for pinging you here, I have revised my answer below that includes a workaround / "hack", let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider dynamic import instead to solve your case, an example of using it would be as follow:

```
function Component() {
  const [json, setJson] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    import('./some.json').then((res) => setJson(res));
  }, []);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(json)}</pre>;
}
```

In most build tools, dynamic import will cause it to split into an additional chunk / file, which is not bundled in the initial bundle / entry file and should make the initial loading fast even if it the content in the JSON file is large.

---

An alternative "hack" would be change your `.json` extension to match with those images. Based on the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) of `create-react-app`. The extension that ends with `bmp`, `gif`, `jpg`, `jpeg` and `png`, will automatically be loaded with `file-loader`.

Assuming your CDN / file servers doesn't have CORS restriction, you can then rename your `.json` file to `.jpg` and obtain the URL generated from there, usage sample below:

```js
import theJsonFile from './some.json.jpg';

const [json, setJson] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(theJsonFile)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => setJson(json));
}, []);

return <pre>{JSON.stringify(json)}</pre>;
```

(It is not the best idea, as `Content-Type` / CORS and other stuff can mess with it, but it is worth a try for small project)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your time. While your answer with dynamic import looks to suggest the best practice, it's a bit farther away from my question. If I get the approach with file-loader working, I will probably accept one of the other answers suggesting it, BUT I expect your answer to be most upvoted and used after all. Does this sound good?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the `file-loader` package.**

Install it using: `npm install file-loader --save-dev`

Add this to your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'json/',
          publicPath: 'json/'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You can then import your JSON file as follows:

```
import json from 'file-loader!./path/to/json/file.json';
```

**If your react app isn't ejected:**

You can use Craco. Add this to your craco.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'json/[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: (path) => path.replace(/^(src|\.\/)/, ''),
          outputPath: (url) => url.replace(/^json\//, ''),
        },
      });

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

Hope this helps!

**Sources:**

*https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader*

*https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/webpack/*

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. My react app is not ejected, so I don't have `webpack.config.js`. Can I accomplish this without ejecting, possibly with Craco by modifying `craco.config.js`?

Comment: @1valdis Yes, you can. I'm editing my answer right now.

Comment: Using your craco config I'm getting the following error: `ERROR in ./src/data.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token "e" (0x65) in JSON at position 0 while parsing near "export default \"..\\\\..."
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709536