# Getting error while trying to create react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to create a React app in VScode. It's giving me some error.
[image]

What should I do to overcome the issue.

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0

Comment: is your network slow. or are you using a VPN?

Comment: Which command are you running in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to have version of Node>=10.16 and version of NPM >=5.6 If this is still not resolved then try this:

1. Clean cache with

- npm cache clean --force

2. Install the latest version of NPM globally as admin:

- npm install -g npm@latest --force

3.clean cache with the command-

-npm cache clean --force

Hope this works out for you