# Unable to deploy to heroku using the Wolfram Alpha API

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, discord.js, wolframalpha

I am developing a discord bot, to use on a server with my friends. One of the functions I wanted it to have is solving equations and giving responses through the Wolfram Alpha API.
I used the Node.js package:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "wolfram-alpha-api": "https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/libraries/javascript/wolfram-alpha-api-1.0.0-rc.1.tgz"
  }
```

Running locally, it works perfectly, but when deploying to Heroku I get a:

```sh
Installing dependencies

Installing node modules

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY

npm ERR! sha512-Ixpm2jwpZA6Q5n9LkLl7Sr42v6ycbM4uuY9BnyAp2J+j/m0QElINtiRMPy1GQUMhz9nDL3fcLganuOG5cFVaaQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-Ixpm2jwpZA6Q5n9LkLl7Sr42v6ycbM4uuY9BnyAp2J+j/m0QElINtiRMPy1GQUMhz9nDL3fcLganuOG5cFVaaQ== but got sha512-yujgD6IWkQvCfiOw8K1xaLvVCSB3NstUZzcolEq5cKIRTbeyEo/1sipK0k0oFcIWX39X6t6fqDlphLCzFVgQCw==. (12482 bytes)

Build failed
```

It said to specify the node version, so I did 15.x, but the problem was not solved. What could be the solution, having in mind that it was working (building and deploying) perfectly before installing the Wolfram Package?

Comment: Please copy and paste _exact, complete_ error messages instead of paraphrasing. See [ask].

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I run \`npm install\`, it returns with \`ERR! code EINTEGRITY\` (npm 5.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0)