# Vercel build failed "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I try to deploy my project on vercel.com, but i have an error. When i made production build in next (local) all it's ok. Near you can see all my logs. I try to change **CI = false** in versel project's option, but it not solve my problem.

```
[22:54:42.833] Cloning gitlab.com/glebassty/xata-next-new (Branch: master, Commit: 8f0af78)
[22:54:44.345] Cloning completed: 1.512s
[22:54:44.661] Installing build runtime...
[22:54:46.542] Build runtime installed: 1.882s
[22:54:47.247] Looking up build cache...
[22:54:47.479] Build Cache not found
[22:54:47.687] Installing dependencies...
[22:54:55.353] npm WARN deprecated redux-devtools-extension@2.13.9: Package moved to @redux-devtools/extension.
[22:54:57.467] npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: (url)
[22:55:01.959] npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
[22:55:02.003] npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
[22:55:02.140] npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
[22:56:04.957] npm WARN tarball tarball data for nanoclone@https://registry.npmjs.org/nanoclone/-/nanoclone-0.2.1.tgz (sha512-wynEP02LmIbLpcYw8uBKpcfF6dmg2vckpqxeH5UcoKEYdExslsdUA4ugFauuaeYdTB76ez6gJW8XAZ6CgkXYxA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
[22:56:04.987] npm WARN tarball tarball data for nanoclone@https://registry.npmjs.org/nanoclone/-/nanoclone-0.2.1.tgz (sha512-wynEP02LmIbLpcYw8uBKpcfF6dmg2vckpqxeH5UcoKEYdExslsdUA4ugFauuaeYdTB76ez6gJW8XAZ6CgkXYxA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
[22:56:06.551] npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
[22:56:06.553] npm ERR! sha512-wynEP02LmIbLpcYw8uBKpcfF6dmg2vckpqxeH5UcoKEYdExslsdUA4ugFauuaeYdTB76ez6gJW8XAZ6CgkXYxA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-wynEP02LmIbLpcYw8uBKpcfF6dmg2vckpqxeH5UcoKEYdExslsdUA4ugFauuaeYdTB76ez6gJW8XAZ6CgkXYxA== but got sha512-wynEP02LmIbLpcYw8uBKpcfF6dmg2vcpKqxeH5UcoKEYdExslsdUA4ugFauuaeYdTB76ez6gJW8XAZ6CgkXYxA==. (2662 bytes)
[22:56:06.554] 
[22:56:06.555] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[22:56:06.555] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-06-26T19_54_47_877Z-debug-0.log
[22:56:06.575] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [When I run `npm install`, it returns with `ERR! code EINTEGRITY` (npm 5.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0)?

Comment: @julimalves , Thank you for help, it's decision of problem