# Facing error while running npx create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

> npm ERR! code E470

npm ERR! 470 status code 470 - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\L173734\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-26T12_23_13_499Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

HOW TO GET RID OF THIS ERROR. My Proxy setting is OFF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545940/when-i-run-npm-install-it-returns-with-err-code-eintegrity-npm-5-3-0?

Answer (score 0):

Try this two command, may be it's work for you

1. `npm cache verify`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`